# Matlab rand and c++ rand()

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am trying to port a matlab code into c++ and found the usage of rand in matlab .
Is matlab's rand function and c++ rand() function same?
If not, is there any inbuilt function for matlab's rand in C++ or opencv?

Comment: Which overload of [matlab's rand()](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) is the code using?

Comment: Matlab is proprietary software, so I guess the only way to find out is to get a job as a developer at mathworks.

Comment: this is the code, which i am trying to convert  `uniform=(1/n)*rand+(0:1/n:1);` @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Because C and C++ do not define the random number sequence produced by `rand()`, it does not really matter.

Comment: @phresnel As you can see at the answer below, C++11 standardises some random number generation. I didn't make any claims about it working everywhere, I was merely asking a question to check if the problem was solvable even using the newer standard.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: Now I see what you were aiming for. That wasn't visible before. (sidenote: I was using g++'s implementation as soon as it was available; afair it was about 2008, for the exact reason of portable random numbers. lore: the boost implementation of mersenne twister once produced different sequences, which I discovered thanks to some nice unit tests within the software I needed the random numbers for (in turn to be able to unit test the results of my software))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the C++ Standard only loosely defines `rand()`, you can **not** assert that it is equivalent to the matlab function.

Fortunately, C++11 now has a suite of generators which **are** standardised in the standard include header `<random>`. For example, `std::mt19937` is a Mersenne twister generator and `std::minstd_rand` is a linear congruential generator which allows you to configure the sequence coefficients.

My guess is that the Matlab generator can be replicated with this latter one. Refer to the Matlab docs for the specific details. Fortunately, testing your code will be trivial.

Comment: Currently, MATLAB uses the Mersenne twister by default.

Answer (score 2):

Bathsheba's guess is almost correct:  Matlab R2017A uses the MT19937 algorithm, not a LC algorithm as its default random number generator; the source for `rand.m` actually includes the copyright notice from the 2002 version of Nishimura and Matsumoto's MT19937 [C Program](https://github.com/notr1ch/opentdm/blob/master/mt19937.c).

In C++ 11,  the default seed is set to 5489, which is identical to Matlab's default seed, (and to the default seed in the referenced C program).

So,  the following Matlab code:

```
rng('default');
a = rand();
a = rand();
a = rand();
```

will output identical values to the C++ code:

```
std::mt19937 rng;
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> urd(0, 1);
a = urd(rng);
/* skip alternate values */ rng();
a = urd(rng);
/* skip alternate values */ rng();
a = urd(rng);
```

Note: To replicate Matlab's output , use `std::uniform_real_distribution<float>` *not* `std::uniform_real_distribution<double>`.

***EDIT***:  Matlab appears to skip every other value after each call to `rand()`, by comparison with C++.  I've compared Matlab output with that of both MSVC 2017 and GCC 5.4;  both of the latter behave identically to each other.  As there are no guarantees regarding the individual values produced by `rand()`, this "non-standard" behavior obviously can't be classed as a bug.
The code samples above take this behavior into account.

Comment: Excellent answer. But why `float` and not `double`? MATLAB outputs doubles.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Not sure: Possibly to maintain  backward-compatibility with previous  versions of Matlab, so that it outputs the same pseudorandom sequence as they did, given the same script.