# Equivalent C++ implementation of MATLAB's rng(seed, 'twister') function

Tags: c++, matlab, random

I'm trying to come up with equivalent ways to generate uniform random variables in MATLAB and C++. In MATLAB, it's straightforward to use the generator `rng(0, 'twister')` to use seed 0 and the Marsenne Twister engine. And then, for example, 5 uniform random numbers can be produced using `rand(5,1)`. According to MATLAB's `rand` documentation, it uses the `mt19937` engine.

I'm struggling to replicate this in C++. I've used the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <random>

static std::random_device rd;
static std::tr1::mt19937 rand_mt(rd());

int main(void)
{
    rand_mt.seed(0);
    for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++)
    {
        std::cout << (double)rand_mt() / ((double)rand_mt.max() - 
        (double)rand_mt.min()) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's a very long shot, but I'm not getting the same outputs from MATLAB and C++. Any problems with the above code that I need to address? Or is there an alternative equivalent implementation in C++?

Comment: not getting the same output for random numbers ? ;) Do you know what the seed is in Matlab?

Comment: Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199376/matlab-rand-and-c-rand

Comment: You could use your own implementation for both languages.

Comment: @user463035818: The seed is 0. The syntax for `rng` is `rng(seed, generator)` according to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html

Comment: oh right, you even mention it in the question. sry ;)

Comment: The second answer in the linked question ^ says to use `std::uniform_real_distribution<float> urd(0, 1);` to replicate MATLAB’s random number stream.

Comment: Could you Post the output you geht and the matlab Code?